# Merging master into develop branch - making sure it works

Tags: git, git-merge

I always have been doing everything on master, but I also have a develop branch here on which last commit was back in 2014. I want to make those branches the same in source tree, which means merging master into develop branch.

I did it, and right now I have something like this:

http://oi61.tinypic.com/2who6du.jpg

Is this ok, can I push the changes? I want to make 100% sure I won't mess up master branch, as there are as you can see 35 commits ahead.

---

And by the way, how can I pop the stashed changes into develop branch after I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: '_I always have been doing everything on master_'. This is basically a bad idea. So why do you want to have dev and master even? If you are working on master anyway and never on dev, I don't see any need for doing a merge. Just abandon  dev and you are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options here:

1. Merge Master to Develop `git checkout develop && git merge master`
2. Remove Develop branch and copy Master `git checkout master && git branch -D develop && git branch develop && git checkout develop`
3. Do Nothing and continue working on Master.

Answer (score 0):

Merging master into develop will never change master. So yes, what you are trying to do is safe.